# How to read data from list<Object> in Java?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects List , being the result of a HQL Query. The Objects of the list contain the data I need. I am doing the following if I know the types of the data :

(Here I know that the query was `Select country, globalAmount, average from table`)

```
 for (Object record : result) {
            Object[] fields = (Object[]) record;
            String country =  (String) fields[0];
            long globalAmount = (Long) fields[1];
            double average = (Double) fields[2];
            System.out.println("Country "+country );
            System.out.println("Global Amount "+globalAmount);
            }
```

The problem is that sometimes, I don't know if I'll be having "Country" or "average" in the Object, and the query can be completely different :

```
Select average, date, message from table
```

Then, to retreive data, I have to do the following :

```
 for (Object record : result) {
        Object[] fields = (Object[]) record;
        double average = (Double) fields[0];
        Timestamp date=  (Timestamp) fields[1];
        String message = (String) fields[2];

        System.out.println("date " +date);
        System.out.println("Message  "+Message);
        System.out.println("Average " + Average);

        }
```

Is there any way that I can dynamically retreive data from this List without having Cast problems?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: doesn't `hibernate` provide straight-forward mapping?

Comment: The problem is that you don't know what the query selects. You should know. Otherwise, obviously there is no way of doing anything useful with the result.

Comment: will you be knowing the query?

Comment: The query depends on the user selection. If He uses country, message, then I should retreive these two. I have no idea what he will be selecting. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not to seem possible. I had to use If blocks to figure out which type I am receiving. Quite long but did not have any other option. The solution provided by Uma Kanth is smart but was not suitable for me though.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a proto-type. What I did here is got all the column names and then based on the column name I'm type casting it to the required type.

This is just a small trick.

```
String query = "Select x, y, z from tablename";
//get the columns here
String colums = query.substring(7, query.indexOf("from") - 1).trim();
String []arrColums = colums.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < arrColums.length; i++)
{
    switch(arrColums[i])
     {
        case "X" : X x = (X)result.get(i);
        case "Y" : Y y = (Y)result.get(i);
     } 
}
```